# Class based vue component property definition: constructor vs. getter / setter vs. mounted lifecycle

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-class-components

I'm just wondering which way is the most reliable to define properties, which should generate an output in the template.

### Define property in constructor:

**Template reference:**

```
<h1>{{msg}}</h1>
```

**Property definition:**

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
  @Component
  export default class Test extends Vue {
    protected msg: string;
    public constructor() {
      super();
      this.msg = 'Today\'s date ' + moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD');
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Output in Browser:**

```
<h1>Today's date 2019/03/07</h1>
```

---

### Define property in mounted lifecycle:

**Template reference:**

```
<h1>{{msg}}</h1>
```

**Property definition:**

```
export default class Test extends Vue {
  protected msg: string = '';
  mounted() {
    this.msg = 'Today\'s date ' + moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD');
  }
}
```

**Output in Browser:**

```
<h1>Today's date 2019/03/07</h1>
```

---

### Define property by get and set, set value in constructor:

**Template reference:**

```
<h1>{{msgText}}</h1>
```

**Property definition:**

```
export default class Test extends Vue {
  protected msg: string = '';
  public constructor() {
    super();
    this.msgText = 'Today\'s date ' + moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD');
  }
  get msgText(): string {
    return this.msg;
  }
  set msgText(msg:string) {
    this.msg = msg;
  }
}
```

**Output in Browser:**

```
<h1>Today's date 2019/03/07</h1>
```

---

### Questions:

- All three ways results in the same output. Is there a golden rule / best practice, how properties should be defined and in which lifecycle?
- Is there a difference, if properties are defined in constructor or in mounted lifecycle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second approach of using `mounted` is preferred over the rest of the approaches. The only change I would suggest is the use of `created` hook instead of `mounted`:

```
export default class Test extends Vue {
  protected msg: string = '';

  created() {
    this.msg = 'Today\'s date ' + moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD');
  }
}
```

Generally, for simple properties, you can directly assign a value at a time of declaration. Use created when your assignment is not simple.

Also, we don't really use constructors when writing the class-based component. The reason behind is that essentially Vue.js components are object-based. The `@Component` decorator is eventually making the component behave like object-based.

Further, if you look at Vue.js component lifecycle methods, then there is no place for a constructor. The initial methods are `beforeCreate` -> `data` -> `created` -> `mounted` and so on. How can a **beforeCreate** execute without an actual call to the **constructor**? That make is really weird to reason about.

***Note 1***: For version 3 of Vue.js, official class-based components are
proposed. Thus, this might change in the near future.

***Note 2***: TypeScript will move `msg` declaration to the **constructor** after compilation and Vue.js seems to work well with it. But it is still unspecified and better be avoided.

Comment: I can't wait for version 3.  I hope you allow TypeScript to do all the heavy lifting making JavaScript an object-oriented language, instead of superimposing your own object oriented hackery on top of JavaScript.